# Memory leak in code using MSXML and smart pointers

Tags: memory-leaks, msxml, msxml6

Something in the following code is leaking memory, but I can't find it.

I've traced through it with a debugger, and even with a debug build, it won't step into the ref counting.  So I've planted pairs of .AddRef() and .Release() to see the ref count of all the pointers at various points.  The thing that stands out to me is the result of `createProcessingInstruction` has a ref count of 2.  If I try to manually decrement it with .Release(), the app triggers an assertion later in the code.

The outer brace in the code below is part of my code, so all of the smart pointers in there should release at the end.  `parser` outlives this section, and was determined to not be part of the leak.

When I run this code in a loop the Commit Size (and naturally Peak Commit Size) grows steadily in all Task Manager, Process Explorer, and programmatically via `GetProcessMemoryInfo`.

```
MSXML2::IXMLDOMDocument3Ptr parser;
HRESULT hr(parser.CreateInstance(__uuidof(MSXML2::DOMDocument60) ) );
if(FAILED(hr) )
{
    throw(XmlException("Failed to create instance of MSXML."));
}
parser->preserveWhiteSpace = VARIANT_TRUE;

...
// Various methods to populate the XML.  Omitted because this was determined to not leak
...

// Something within this section is leaking.
{
    const std::wstring wstrXmlDeclaration(L" version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-16\"");
    // TODO:  If this is expensive, maybe store an instance?
    IXMLDOMProcessingInstructionPtr pProcessingInstruction(
        parser->createProcessingInstruction(
            L"xml",
            wstrXmlDeclaration.c_str()
        )
    );
    if(!pProcessingInstruction)
    {
        throw(XmlException("Failed to create instruction for encoding.") );
    }
    DWORD ulRefCount = pProcessingInstruction->AddRef();
    ulRefCount = pProcessingInstruction->Release();

    // NOTE: ulRefCount is 2 here (??)

    MSXML2::IXMLDOMNodePtr pFirstChild(
        parser->GetfirstChild()
    );
    if(!pFirstChild)
    {
        throw(XmlException("Failed to get XML Declaration of XML Document.") );
    }

    const std::wstring wstrFirstChildName(pFirstChild->nodeName);
    assert(wstrFirstChildName == L"xml");
    if(wstrFirstChildName != L"xml")
    {
        throw(XmlException("Unexpected first element (XML Declaration) in XML."));
    }

    MSXML2::IXMLDOMNodePtr pOldChild(
        parser->replaceChild(
            static_cast<MSXML2::IXMLDOMNode*>(pProcessingNode),
            static_cast<MSXML2::IXMLDOMNode*>(pFirstChild)
        )
    );
    if(!pOldChild)
    {
        throw(XmlException("Failed to apply specified encoding.") );
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be great to see a sample that one can take and build upon. Otherwise, it's hard to say what's wrong with the code. But I can suggest running the problematic code in a loop and then profiling it with a memory profiler like Deleaker.

Comment: Thanks @ArtemRazin I'm working on both of those suggestions already, along with trying process of elimination.